# How to add clickable items to AChartEngine Line Chart?

Tags: android, achartengine

There is the following code from samples:

```
/**
 * Copyright (C) 2009, 2010 SC 4ViewSoft SRL
 *  
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *  
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *  
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;

/**
 * Average temperature demo chart.
 */
public class AverageTemperatureChart extends AbstractDemoChart {
  /**
   * Returns the chart name.
   * 
   * @return the chart name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return "Average temperature";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the chart description.
   * 
   * @return the chart description
   */
  public String getDesc() {
    return "The average temperature in 4 Greek islands (line chart)";
  }

  /**
   * Executes the chart demo.
   * 
   * @param context the context
   * @return the built intent
   */
  public Intent execute(Context context) {
    String[] titles = new String[] { "Crete", "Corfu", "Thassos", "Skiathos" };
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 });
    }
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { 12.3, 12.5, 13.8, 16.8, 20.4, 24.4, 26.4, 26.1, 23.6, 20.3, 17.2,
        13.9 });
    values.add(new double[] { 10, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 26, 26, 23, 18, 14, 11 });
    values.add(new double[] { 5, 5.3, 8, 12, 17, 22, 24.2, 24, 19, 15, 9, 6 });
    values.add(new double[] { 9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 23, 26, 25, 22, 18, 13, 10 });
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW };
    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND,
        PointStyle.TRIANGLE, PointStyle.SQUARE };
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
    }
    setChartSettings(renderer, "Average temperature", "Month", "Temperature", 0.5, 12.5, -10, 40,
        Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, buildDataset(titles, x, values),
        renderer, "Average temperature");
    return intent;
  }

}
```

That's code from samples of ACharEngine library just draws a simple Line chart. 
It is possible to set listener for clicking by lines? It it's impossible, may be there is some way to set listener for clicking by points?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) class in the example, lines #157 to #179.

http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java

Comment: Thank you. But how can I fix it for my task? I don't use View class. Are there any interfaces for set listener?

Comment: If you don't use views then you cannot.

Comment: If you look at my code which I inserted in my post I had used Intent for executing a Chart. How can I use View instead of Intent?

Comment: If you look at the code I referred in my answer, you will see how.

Comment: @Dan I think the link in your answer is edited and line #217 doesn't exist. I'm very interested in this topic. Is there any link, information or references that I can refer to?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! There is one more thing I wanted to ask, any idea how I can I drag the point and move it around the chart?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Maybe you can ask a separate one?